# pass realsesense RGB-D images from unity to c++

Tags: c++, unity-game-engine, realsense

I got both depthImage and colorImage in Unity using realsense camera and I want to processing these images in C++.

I tried to transform these images to mat,I use opencvsharp in Unity, and pass them to C++, but I failed.We can't directly pass Mat between unity and c++.

Does anyone have some good ideas to pass RGB-D images to from unity to C++.Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Why not process them directly in Cpp before Unity? That would be more performant and all the tracking is done on the Cpp end